# When to use Relative pronoun

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, relative-clauses

In the sentence below, the relative pronoun "which" is used after "many of". What about using "them" instead of "which"? Would it be grammatical and would there be any differences between those two sentences?

> In Britain there are a number of Sunday newspapers, many of *which* are connected with the "dailies", though not run by the same editor and stuff

Comment: It's relative pronoun. Not relative noun. You can definitely use "them" instead of"which" but it will not be a relative clause like it is in case of your original sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my question. Do you feel any differences between the sentence with or without the relative pronoun?

Comment: No difference in meaning, neither has any effect on the correctness. But it changes grammatical structure as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If you replace "which" with "them", you get a *comma splice*, which is an error where two main clauses are joined by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use "many of them", I can see two ways of adjusting the sentence.

The simplest is to divide the sentence into two sentences:

1. "In Britain there are a number of Sunday newspapers. *Many of them are connected with the "dailies"*, though not run by the same editor and staff."

If you don't want to divide the sentence, you can adjust it in this way:

2. "In Britain there are a number of Sunday newspapers, *many of them connected with the "dailies"*, though not run by the same editor and staff."

The second method, instead of using a relative clause, uses a participial clause. The meaning is the same.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! It's really useful so I'll use your explanation to my students.